# Is the equal a priori probability postulate a postulate or a corollary?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In the non-relativistic statistical mechanics, I suppose that we can derive equal probability postulate directly from *Liouville equation*. But why does *the equal a priori probability postulate* appear as a postulate in so many textbooks?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the equiprobability postulate, No you can not. it comes, not from Liouville theorems which basically say that The Hamiltonian flow conserves the Lesbegues measure on the phase space. The equiprobability comes from the Ergodic theorem, if you have a mixinig measure on your phase space (so ergodic) you have certainly equiprobability (it is rather intuitive), you can not prove the ergodicity (only for finite cases, using Birkhoff's theorem for example, but in the usual stat mech. problems, it is ergodic)